# Reference recommendations for Convex Geometry

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation, convex-geometry

So I'm an undergraduate with limited knowledge of analysis, and none of topology. I'm trying to study Convex Geometry, and I'm looking for recommendations for the same - in terms of books, video playlists, course webpages, etc.

It will be great if the book/resource is suited for self-study; but I don't mind if it's not!

One book I came across after a little search is *Lectures on Convex Geometry* by *Daniel Hug and W. Weil* - though I don't know much about it. Thank you!

Comment: google convex geometry or (lectures on) convex sets and you get plenty of links (but this apparently you already did). One book that I like, even if it may not be most general and complete (if only considers $\mathbb R^n$), I find it well written and easier to follow (and complete enough in terms of presenting plenty of ideas) is Steven R. Lay, Convex sets and their applications. First edition 1982, review at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183550147 Also, Dover's reprint https://www.amazon.com/Convex-Their-Applications-Dover-Mathematics/dp/0486458032 (Also,search MSE for old answers.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous references; here are my 3 favorites:

A superb introduction is
[1] Ball, Keith. "An elementary introduction to modern convex geometry." Flavors of geometry 31 (1997): 1-58.
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.77.3836&rep=rep1&type=pdf

A wonderful but challenging  book is:
[2] Gilles Pisier, The volume of convex bodies and Banach space geometry,
Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics, vol. 94, Cambridge
University Press, Cambridge, 1989.

The combinatorial view:
[3] Danzer, L., B. Grünbaum, and V. Klee. "Helly’s Theorem and its Relatives (Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics VII)." American Mathematical Society (Providence, RI, 1963): 101-180.